# Deployed Tomcat application loading old SWF

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am attempting to update a Tomcat web application on a Red Hat server (that also uses Apache). Currently, attempting to deploy an new WAR file and it is not properly updating the application. Through clearing browser cache, I'm able to reach the newer version, but it constantly switches from old to new version with each refresh. After a little bit it reverts back to the old version entirely.

I have tried to clear cache created by Apache Tomcat in the tomcat/work directory, but that has not have any impact. I've removed the tomcat webapps folder entirely, recreated it, and deployed the application, but still no luck. From viewing the logs provided by tomcat, it looks like the application is successfully being deployed as well and there are no errors on that end.

Has anyone experienced this same issue?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:apache] tag - if you want to keep it, please mention more than it being deployed on the server as well. The way the question is currently phrased, it's unrelated to Apache httpd.

Comment: Look in the logs if both versions of the application are started. Also look for `<Context>` elements in your `server.xml` and for `*.xml` files in the `conf/Catalina` folder.